# Find jobs and dependencies run between two timestamps

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, jobs

I would like to know what jobs ran and dependencies (what triggered them) between two timestamps or dates.

I have been looking in all the oracle views. I cannot find anything like this in the `dba_scheduler_jobs` view.

Comment: dba_scheduler_job_run_details for when jobs ran.  What triggered them straightforward for any jobs on a run schedule, however, ad-hoc jobs (via dbms_scheduler.run_job()) are going to be tricky...

Comment: how can I query the dba_scheduler_job_run_details so that it returns the jobs between two timestamps.. we would already be grateful to have this information.

Comment: actual_start_date is the datetime the job started.  log_date is the date the job finished.  Beyond that, if you really need help with datetime comparisons, this should help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73516/compare-dates-in-oracle-sql

Answer (score 1):

There is no guaranteed method for this. The closest you can get to this is: `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`, but:

- logging for scheduler jobs can be disabled, so it does not necessarily contain all jobs runs
- there is no information about what started the job

Also, there is no history for `DBMS_JOB` jobs.